# how to execute predefined CSS file in Susy grid project?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, compass-sass, susy-compass

I am new to susy grid. Can anyone tell me how to implement pre-defined css file in my susy grid project? I am using compass plugin.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you provide more detail, please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get what you meant, but to add already compiled .css files in your sass file, just use the `@import` function – CSS files are not parsed by SASS when imported.